# Concatenating two R.string leads to numbers

Tags: android, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two string which I get from resources as R.string but instead of having a result like

> My String 1. My String 2

I have something like this

> 32908529. 23492492

I am performing the concatenation either by using

a StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder strbuilder = new StringBuilder();
strbuilder.append(R.string.body_1);
strbuilder.append(". ");
strbuilder.append(R.string.body_2);
```

or a simple "+"

```
String s = R.string.body_1 + ". " + R.string.body_2
```

Any ideas?

I am using Android Studio in Windows 10, if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```
String s = getString(R.string.body_1) + ". " + getString(R.string.body_2)
```

instead of

```
String s = R.string.body_1 + ". " + R.string.body_2
```

R.String.body_1 will return the id for that resource
getString(R.String.body_1) will return value of that id